# How do I resolve this python runtime error in Azure SQL Managed Instances?

Tags: sql-server, python, azure-sql-managed-instance, external-scripts

We recently setup a new managed instance through the [program that allows you to try it for free](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/free-offer?view=azuresql). When trying to run the following code from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-python-create-script?context=%2Fazure%2Fazure-sql%2Fmanaged-instance%2Fcontext%2Fml-context&view=azuresqldb-mi-current&preserve-view=true#check-python-version):

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'Python',
  @script=N'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))'
```

The code fails after 300 seconds with the following error:

> Msg 39012, Level 16, State 14, Line 0
>
> Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script for request id: A1D8A9DA-DBB1-4EDE-B589-3AAFD4241D18. Please check the requirements of 'Python' runtime.
>
> STDERR message(s) from external script:
>
> SQLSatellite Run() failed.  Error code:0x8007271d.
>
> SqlSatelliteCall error: SQLSatellite Run() failed.  Error code:0x8007271d.
>
> STDOUT message(s) from external script:
>
> SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\WFRoot\Ext\Python.9.4.8.3\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 605, in rx_sql_satellite_call
>
> rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
>
> File "D:\WFRoot\Ext\Python.9.4.8.3\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 375, in rx_native_call
>
> ret = px_call(functionname, params)
>
> RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming even basic functionality breaks, such as asking for the version?

I doubt there is anything you'll be able to do on your end as this is a managed instance and hosted in Azure. There is most likely something wrong with the set of processes in charge of spinning up the polybase functionality which is leading to the timeout (`0x8007271d` = `WSAEACCES`, `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.`) or some other internal issue(s) in the communications between the polybase process and the SQL Engine.

Your best bet is to open a support ticket and have it investigated on the backend as there are a myriad of things it could be. Sadly, that's the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

It is a path issue. You need to edit some paths in the pythonlauncher.config file. Here is a good [step-by-step troubleshooting guide](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/fixing-mls-python-services-to-load-the-runtime) that can be useful for you and others facing the specific problem you are facing now.